# System.TimeoutException using SerialPort in C#

Tags: c#, .net, serial-port

I have a system which sends a command to a list of serial ports and displays the returns in a RichTextBox.
When I was 10 serial ports, the program worked well, now I'm working with about 60 and it returns the following error:

```
Problem signature:
Problem Event Name: CLR20r3
Problem Signature 01:   jporttestot.exe
Problem Signature 02:   1.0.0.0
Problem Signature 03:   51db05c7
Problem Signature 04:   System
Problem Signature 05:   4.0.0.0
Problem Signature 06:   4ba1dff4
Problem Signature 07:   3140
Problem Signature 08:   b3
Problem Signature 09:   System.TimeoutException
OS Version: 6.1.7601.2.1.0.256.1
Locale ID:  1046
Additional Information 1:   0a9e
Additional Information 2:   0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789
Additional Information 3:   0a9e
Additional Information 4:   0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789
Read our privacy statement online:
http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=104288&clcid=0x0409
If the online privacy statement is not available, please read our privacy statement offline:
C:\Windows\system32\en-US\erofflps.txt
```

Below is my code:

```
 public partial class Form1 : Form
        {
            List<SerialPort> serialPort = new List<SerialPort>();


            private delegate void SetTextDeleg(string text);

            public Form1()
            {
                InitializeComponent();
            }

            private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                int baudRate = Convert.ToInt32(txtBaudRate.Text);
                var portNames = SerialPort.GetPortNames();
                foreach (var port in portNames)
                {
                    SerialPort sp;
                    sp = new SerialPort(port, baudRate, Parity.None, 8, StopBits.One);
                    sp.Handshake = Handshake.None;
                    sp.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(sp_DataReceived);
                    sp.ReadTimeout = 500;
                    sp.WriteTimeout = 500;

                    serialPort.Add(sp);
                    listPorts.Items.Add(port);
                }
            }

            private void listPorts_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {

            }

            private void button1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                boxLogs.Text = "";
                String comando = txtComando.Text.Trim();

                foreach (var sp in serialPort)
                {
                    // Open port
                    try
                    {
                        if (!sp.IsOpen)
                            sp.Open();

                        //sp.Write("at\r\n");
                        sp.Write("at\r\n");
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        boxLogs.Text = "Erro ao abrir/escrever na porta serial :: " + ex.Message +"\n";
                    }
                }
            }

            void sp_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
            {
                Thread.Sleep(500);
                SerialPort sp = (SerialPort)sender;
                string data = sp.ReadLine();
                data = sp.ReadLine();
                this.BeginInvoke(new SetTextDeleg(si_DataReceived), new object[] { sp.PortName + " - Retorno: " + data });
            }

            private void si_DataReceived(string data)
            {
                String retorno = data.Trim();
                boxLogs.Text += retorno + "\n";
            }

            private void txtComando_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {

            }

            private void txtBaudRate_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {

            }

        }
```

Comment: well maybe 500 is just not enough there and this situation should be handled?

Comment: I increased the timeout to 5000 and the problem still continues!

Comment: Does it happen every time on different port?

Comment: Happens right when I click the button

Comment: Do you have a stack trace? In which function does this happen? Uppon writing or reading?

Answer (score 0):

When you have so many of SerialPort objects, your port may still not be open at the time you're calling Write() on it. System needs some time to actually complete the operation. Try Thread.Sleep() for some time after Open() and see what happens (your UI will freeze though). Maybe like this?

```
 if (!sp.IsOpen)  
{
    sp.Open();
    Thread.Sleep(200);
    sp.Write("at\r\n");  
}
```

By the way, where are you calling Close()? MSDN states:

> "The best practice for any application is to wait for some amount of
>   time after calling the Close method before attempting to call the Open
>   method, as the port may not be closed instantly."